# Gauss: Changes to TangoImageBuffer?

Tags: google-project-tango

I haven't seen anything in the release notes about this, but has the TangoImageBuffer data been changed in the latest Gauss release?

I had written code to convert the YUV12 data to RGB (was working in Fermat), however the new release seems to have broken this. I've also noticed that the buffer width has changed from 1536 to 1280, so it's possible the Marshall.Copy is copying an incorrect set of bytes.

Any insight on this would be very helpful!

Edit: Here's a screenshot of what the previously working code is now showing: [image: screenshot of gauss image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out its not that big a deal - what you are receiving from Tango now is a straight RGBA image - the code I put up earlier to obtain the RGBA from YUV can now just be omitted, it's already done

Comment: Yup. This is the right answer. Curious how you figured this out? Was it by trial and error or has the change been documented somewhere?

Comment: Soon as I saw stride was equal to width I had a pretty good idea - first try and done - like that happens a lot  :-/